# Popular Dictionary Application for a Linux System [Ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, dictionary

What is most popular dictionary in Linux? I am beginner and don't know which one to install, because Application Center Ubuntu lists me a lot of dictionaries when I search for a dictionary. Which one do you recommend me to install? Or should I download another one from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StarDict](http://stardict.sourceforge.net/Dictionaries.php) FTW.

Comment: And sdcv - the CLI frontend for its dictionaries.

Comment: From the linked page: The original StarDict project has recently been removed from SourceForge due to copyright infringement reports. Most of the files were lost with the demise of the project. The project has re-emerged [here](http://stardict.sourceforge.net/Dictionaries.php) since then, though the legal issues may never have been resolved. StarDict hasn't seen any active development for many years, while the world around hasn't stood still.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the `dict` command is most popular.

```
dict banana
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu & Gnome ship with the [Gnome Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome-dictionary) by default. I believe it is part of the Office applications. Since it's the default, this will make it the most popular dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Most applications do use ispell or aspell implementations.

Not all the dictionaries support all the languages. You should ask for a dictionary specific to the language.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want one that works well for you, or the most popular?

Ubuntu makes it easy to install and remove those programs, so install them all and give each a cursory glance (e.g. use them several times over several days) and see which best meets your needs.